# RPI-Cam-Web-Interface: Permission denied. Already enabled the camera

Tags: camera, web-server, web-interface

I followed this [tutorial](https://quavoce.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/how-to-make-a-59-fully-featured-raspberry-pi-home-security-camera-newbie-guide/comment-page-1/#comment-49).

At step #23, I used the exact same setting option. And pressed Ok and Start Now. But it just kept repeating:

> mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
>   sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied

The same exact senetence repeating again and again. After some time, it would stop repeating. But if I pressed Enter, then it would restarted the repeating:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface $ mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
>   sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied
>   mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
>   sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied
>   mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
>   sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied
>   mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)

I saw an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544872/4747885) no Stack Overflow to this problem. Enabled the camera. But the problem wasn't resolved. I used the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133024/4747885) to the same question, and got this:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd RPi_Web_Interface
>   bash: cd: RPi_Web_Interface: No such file or directory
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /RPi_Web_Interface_Installer.sh
>   bash: /RPi_Web_Interface_Installer.sh: No such file or directory
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $

I just read [here](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) that :

> IMPORTANT NOTE: This is for the Raspberry Pi camera only. It does NOT support USB cameras.

Now the question is C**an I use this interface with USB camera?**

Comment: I use motion with my Logitech USB web cam. That's not "this interface" so not really an answer to your question, but USB cameras do work with Pi. https://motion-project.github.io/

Comment: But how can I take photo and record videos while its live streaming?

Comment: I did make it work using this tutorial, but I cannot take photo while its streaming to my browser. https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/

Comment: I use motion to stream and take pictures at regular intervals (e.g. for timelapse).  I've also used motion to take a movie of my cat when she entered the garage (motion detection). Unfortunately, I do not know the interface you are asking about. :(

Comment: But can you press a button to take a photo whenever you want to take a photo? Btw, could you give a link to a tutorial on using motion to take photos? I am very new to RPi.

Comment: Hmm. I've not done the button push thing since I'm just creating plant growth timelapses. But here is a tutorial that may help. Searching for it was tricky because "motion" is so common. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/ If this works for you I can write up an offishul answer.

Comment: This final result in this tutorial doesn't have the feature to take photos. It just streams a live video like in the tutorial I just showed you.

Comment: Can we move this to chat?

Comment: ok where do we chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78551/discussion-between-oyamist-aeroponics-and-most-venerable-sir).

Comment: are you able to see and respond to chat?